# Python class-dependent template?

Tags: python, templates, mako

i want to create a widget depending on the class of the object, is there a simple way to do that in mako?  for example

class A might have attributes A and B

while

class B might have attributes A, B and C

is there a pattern for this?

i want to make a super class that they but inherit, but if I have a function print and call it by calling obj.print(), but i don't want to put template code into class functions

for example, i have a widget that goes

```
<div>obj.a</div>
<div>obj.b</div>
<div>obj.c</div>
<div>obj.d</div>
```

but if it's object B, i want it to go

```
<div>obj.a</div>
<div>obj.b</div>
<div>obj.c</div>
```

etc, but was wondering if theres a clean way to do it

Comment: Please take time to clarify your question, it is very difficult to understand what exactly is your problem.

Comment: thx, added clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a method which returns `[a, b]` in class A and `[a, b, c]` in class B.

Then you can do:

```
% for stuff in thing.return_list_of_stuff:
    <div>${stuff}</div>
% endfor
```

(I've never used mako, so the syntax might be incorect.)

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but harder to deal with more customization